# Installing multiple ASP.NET Core services on AWS elasticbeanstalk with Linux results in error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to setup an ebs Linux environment where I deploy to asp.net core APIs. One of them will start on port 5000 and the other on port 5005. Based on the documentation I am uploading a zip with the following folder structure:

```
api1/**    
api2/**    
.platform/ngnix/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_custom.conf    
Procfile
```

**01_cusom.conf contain:**

```
location /app1{
     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5005;
     proxy_http_version  1.1;

     proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   Connection $http_connection;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
location /app2{
     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     proxy_http_version  1.1;

     proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   Connection $http_connection;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

**Procfile contains:**

```
app1: dotnet app1/app1.dll
app2: dotnet app2/app2.dll
```

**app1 and app2 contains the dlls for each of my applications.**

**When I upload the zip I receive the following log:**

2020/08/06 09:17:59.881512 [ERROR] startProcess Failure: starting process "app1" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start app1.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for app1.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status app1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

2020/08/06 09:17:59.881539 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [FlipApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: Register application failed because the registration of proc app1 failed:
startProcess Failure: starting process "app1" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start app1.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for app1.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status app1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I should mention that this is my first time working with AWS in general so I probably might be missing something very basic.

After restarting the ec2 instance it seems that now it's working for one of the APIs. The one on port 5000, but not the one on port 5005. This leads me to believe that my nginx configuration is not being taken into consideration. Does anyone know if this is the case and what I can do about it?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Can you also provide a link to the documentation you used?